# What is the volume of $A'EF-ABD$?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

[image]

$ABCD-A'B'C'D'$ is a cube with a edge length of $6$.

$E$ is the midpoint of $A'B'$ and $F$ is the point on $A'D'$ where $|A'F|=2|D'F|$.

The question is: what is the volume of $A'EF-ABD$ ?

---

I have two methods, one is integral.

[image]

Let $x$ be the length of $AA_2$, I get $$V_{A'EF-ABD}=\int_{0}^{6}\frac{1}{2}(6-\frac{x}{2})(6-\frac{x}{3})dx=69$$

The other method is to divide it into two parts.

[image]

\begin{align*}
V_{A'EF-ABD} &= V_{D-A'EF}+V_{D-A'EBA} \\ 
 &= \frac{1}{2}\times 3\times 4\times 6\times \frac{1}{3}+(3+6)\times 6\times \frac{1}{2}\times 6\times \frac{1}{3}\\ 
 &= 12+54\\ 
 &= 66\\ 
\end{align*}

It's obvious that $69\neq 66$, what causes the difference?

Comment: I'm gonna throw away my brains... just getting the same figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective of the following argumentation is to show that the rigid body at stake is not a  not a truncated pyramid. The calculation based on the integration of the surface area of right triangles is all right. What is the problem then?

Let $A$ be the origin of our spatial coordinate system. Also, let $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AD}$, and $\overrightarrow{AA'}$ be the $x$, the $y$, and the $z$ axes, respectively. Then, looking from above (if we cut the $BDEF$ surface with planes parallel to the $xy$ plane)  we see straight lines whose equations are:

$$y=-\frac{1}{18}(z+18)x+6-\frac{z}{3},\ 0\le z\le 6,$$

where the slope and the $y$ crossing depend on $z$.

In terms of $x,y,z$ this is not an equation of a plain.

That is, $BDEF$ is not a plain. The equation of the $BDEF$ surface is 
$$-y-\frac{1}{18}zx-x-\frac{z}{3}+6=0$$

or in an explicit form:
$$z(x,y)=\frac{6-x-y}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x}{18}}.$$

Whit the little help from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%286-x-y%29%2F%281%2F18*x%2B1%2F3%29%2C+0.0%3Cx%3C6.0%2C+0.0%3Cy%3C6.0) and after some cosmetics, here is the surface at stake:
[image]

**EDITED**

Clearly, the part we are interested in looks like a plane. The Alpha figure is not convincing though. In the figure the surface looks, from above, like a convex surface. If it was convex from above then the pyramidal calculations ought to have given a greater volume than the (correct) integration. This is why I compared two curves: (1) the straight line joining the points $E$ and $D$ and (2) the line running on the surface right below $DE$:

[image]

It is clear that the surface is concave from above (at least along the line examined.)

Answer (score 1):

The quadrilateral $BEFD$ is not planar. This means you are missing some of the volume because the line $ED$ runs *through* your solid rather than *on* it.

Comment: Can someone confirm the correctness of my answer? I'm having doubts...

Comment: BEFD is definitely not planar. The two methods in the question would seem to describe two different solids: the integral method would describe a solid in which BEFD curved slightly as the vertex along BE moved faster than that along DF. The second method describes a solid with all planar faces, in which there is another edge ED dividing "face BEFD" into faces EBD and EFD.

Comment: @G-man : I was having doubts, too. Even after my answer was accepted. I feel like I owe you an **EDIT** to my answer. (and a vote up) Please, see my final edit.